# Bind Popup on a Button in a GridView Column

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, popup

I've a little Problem. On my Window, i've a `GridView` and on every Row of the `GridView` is a `Button` (The Button is Part of the `GridViewColumn.CellTemplate`). Now i want, that when i press the `Button`, a `Popup` should be open under the pressed `Button`.

But how i can bind the `Popup` on the `Button` in a Grid because the `Button` is dynamic (for every Row one `Button`).

```
 <Popup Name="popup_Zuordnungen">
        <controls:Anlagenzuordnung Grid.Row="3" x:Name="VertragsAnlagenPopup" Margin="0,20,0,0">     </controls:Anlagenzuordnung>
 </Popup>

<ListView Grid.Row="1" Name="lv_Leistungserbringer" DataContextChanged="lv_Leistungserbringer_DataContextChanged" SelectionChanged="lv_Leistungserbringer_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:VertragsLeistungserbringerZuordnung}}, Path=DataSource}" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="ID">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" Width="40" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn Header="Bezeichnung">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Beschreibung}" Width="500" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>

                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Zuordnungen anzeigen" Name="cmd_Zuordnungen"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

The Button is in the last Column.

Cab anywhere help me?

Comment: Use `Command` on button, show popup on Executed event handler....

Comment: I know how i can Show the Popup. What i want to know is how can i set the PlacementTarget from the Popup on the Button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `Window` with code-behind?

In that case, you can simply add a click event to your button (in the `DataTemplate`), and handle the popup placement in the event handler:

XAML:

```
...
<DataTemplate>
    <Button Content="Zuordnungen anzeigen" Name="cmd_Zuordnungen"
            Click="cmd_Zuordnungen_Click" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Code:

```
private void cmd_Zuordnungen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    popup_Zuordnungen.IsOpen = false;
    popup_Zuordnungen.PlacementTarget = (Button)sender;
    popup_Zuordnungen.IsOpen = true;
}
```